# How can I remove rotted wood from framing under a window?

Tags: framing, windows, rot

Going to be replacing windows, found mold/mildew/rot under one of the old window sills. Will I be able to remove this board without damaging drywall?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think I'd try. Drywall is cheap and easy to repair, and you may need to dig to replace all the damaged wood; simpler to resign yourself to opening and closing the patient\\\\\\\wall at the outset.

Answer (score 1):

The method of repair will depend on the extend of the rot.

To test that use a nail and see how far can you drive it in BY HAND.

If it is mainly surface (not deep) you can use wood rot epoxy repair kit. It is two compound mastic that hardens. Scrape some of the top rot and apply the wood rot repair.

If the nail goes in more then 1/2 inch, the wood needs to be replaced.

To replace, you have to remove the drywall. You can try removing it in one piece by using a magnet and finding the screws, or using utility knife and cutting.

Comment: Was able to dig into it with a wire brush easily and it's pretty soft. I'm assuming replacement. drywall is nailed on. We're having windows replaced so there should be access to this wood from the exterior. Didn't know if I could simply cut it with a receprocating saw and remove/replace easily with minimal damage.